# jQuery custom event is not triggering on first pass, works otherwise?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-events

I'm emitting a custom event from a plugin I'm building, and while it will work whenever it is called normally, it will not work during my plugin initialization function, and I'm not sure why. I attach my plugin to my page:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input.tagger').suggest();        
});
```

Here is my abridged plugin, with the relevant content:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.suggest = function() {
        // Provide an accessor to the bound element
        var self = this;
        var containerElement, 
            wrapperElement,
            submissionElement, // this
            tagsElement, 
            inputElement, 
            suggestionElement;

        var currentTags = new Array();

        // Create a new tag when asked
        var createNewTag = function(tag) {
            // trim and convert the text to lowercase
            tagText = $.trim(tag.toLowerCase());

            tagsElement.append('<div class="'+ tagText +'">'+ tagText +'<span class="remove">X</span></div>');
            currentTags.push(tagText);
            inputElement.val("");
            containerElement.trigger('tag:added');
        }

        var actions = function() {

            containerElement.on('tag:added', function() {
                console.log(wrapperElement.width());
                console.log(tagsElement.outerWidth());
                var inputElementWidth = wrapperElement.width() - tagsElement.outerWidth() - 1; // Why minus one? Who knows.
                inputElement.css({'width': inputElementWidth});
            });
        }

        // init
        (function() { 

            // 'containerElement' and such like defined and added to the DOM here.

            // Define some variables that refer to elements that I have dynamically created above. Once all the elements are setup, check to see if there's any default values in the input that we need to include
            var defaultTags = self.val().split(" ");
            $.each(defaultTags, function(index, defaultTag) {
                createNewTag(defaultTag);
            });
        }());
        return this;
    }
}(jQuery));
```

As you can see, I run an `init` function as an IIFE first, and call the `createNewTag` function which should emit a `tag:added` event if it occurs. If I call `createNewTag` from outside the `init` function in another portion of my code, the `tag:added` event takes place, whereas if it's called from within `init`, `createNewTag` will run, but there will be no event triggered.

Why is this?

Comment: @ArunPJohny it doesn't matter. `actions` is just a function to hold all my events, etc.

Comment: who is calling `actions`?

Comment: the only reason for the problem could be you are triggring the event before the handler is registered

Comment: so who and when the `actions` method is called matters

Comment: @ArunPJohny `actions` is never called directly. my `init` IIFE is placed last in my code so actions and all the handler registrations will have already occurred.

Comment: I don't think so... since actions is a method somebody have to invoke it

Comment: @ArunPJohny okay, so I also have a click handler bound in the actions method. How is that being called when I click on something if actions isn't called?

Comment: can you create a https://jsfiddle.net to recreate the problem

Comment: Nowhere in your code shown do you actually set the `containerElement`. Please provide the complete code for the plugin include the bit commented as `"containerElement' and such like defined and added to the DOM here."` :)